# observe_field in a rails 2.2.2 app is not saving checkbox value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following form in a rails app which is not working:

```
<% form_remote_for :team  do |f| %>
  <tr>
    <% 1.upto(12) do |i| %>
      <td>
        <%= f.check_box @mo[i] %>
        <%= observe_field 'team_' + @mo[i], 
          :method => :put,
          :with => "$(@mo[i] + '=') + $('team_'+@mo[i]).value" %>
      </td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

@mo[i] is the name of the field in the database (e.g. jan, feb, mar,... dcm). The code would look like this if i were to write them all out:

```
<% form_remote_for :team  do |f| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <%= f.check_box :jan %>
        <%= observe_field 'team_jan', 
          :method => :put,
          :with => "'jan=' + $('team_jan').value"
    </td>
    ...
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your :with string doesn't make any sense to me. What's it trying to do? Give an example of what you want the parameters to look like.

Comment: @BenLee, does the additional info in the question clarify it for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your :with statements has some syntax problems, and you are also not interpolating your ruby variables correctly. Try this:

```
  :with => "'#{@mo[i]}=' + $('team_#{@mo[i]}').value"
```

I derived this by taking your intended output `'jan=' + $('team_jan').value` and replacing all instances of `jan` with `#{@mo[i]}`, which is the way to interpolate your variable that contains the month name.

Also, you probably need to add a `:url` option to tell where your ajax call should be sent. Something like this:

```
<%= observe_field 'team_jan',
        :url => team_path(@team),
        :method => :put,
        :with => "'#{@mo[i]}=' + $('team_#{@mo[i]}').value" %>
```

I am guessing here that your desired endpoint is `team_path(@team)`, but replace it if it is not.

Comment: appreciate what you taught me but it still isn't saving the value. Thanks, though. Double checked to make sure it wasn't attributes accessible issue.

Comment: @Jay, see my updated answer with stuff about the `:url` option.